# Would like to return a fake row if there is no match to my pair (for a year)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to clean up some data returned from a query. This query :

```
select seriesId,
       startDate,
       reportingCountyId,
       countyId,
       countyName,
       pocId,
       pocValue
  from someTable
 where seriesId = 147
   and pocid = 2
   and countyId in (2033,2040)
```

order by startDate

usually returns 2 county matches for all years:

```
seriesId    startDate   reportingCountyId   countyId    countyName  pocId   pocValue
147 2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 6910    2040    CountyOne       2   828

147 2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2998    2033    CountyTwo   2   4514
147 2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 3000    2040    CountyOne       2   2446

147 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 3018    2033    CountyTwo   2   5675
147 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 4754    2040    CountyOne       2   2265

147 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 3894    2033    CountyTwo   2   6250
147 2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 3895    2040    CountyOne       2   2127

147 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 4842    2033    CountyTwo   2   5696
147 2008-01-01 00:00:00.000 4846    2040    CountyOne       2   2013

147 2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 6786    2033    CountyTwo   2   2578
147 2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 6817    2040    CountyTwo   2   1933

147 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 6871    2040    CountyOne       2   1799
147 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 6872    2033    CountyTwo   2   4223

147 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 8314    2033    CountyTwo   2   3596
147 2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 8315    2040    CountyOne       2   1559
```

But note please that the first entry has only CountyOne for 2004. I would like to return a fake row for CountyTwo for a graph I am doing. It would be sufficient to fill it like CountyOne only with pocValue = 0.

thanks!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if you need blank row for that countryid)

```
; with CTE AS 

(SELECT 2033 As CountryID UNION SELECT 2040),

CTE2 AS
(
       seriesId, startDate, reportingCountyId, 
       countyId, countyName, pocId, pocValue 
       from someTable where 
       seriesId = 147 and pocid = 2 and countyId in (2033,2040) 
       order by startDate
)

SELECT x1.CountyId, x2.*, IsNull(pocValue,0) NewpocValue FROM CTE x
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 x2 ON x1.CountyId = x2.reportingCountyId
```

Comment: THanks! I'm really confused about how to add your query to my query or even run it on its own. Getting lots of syntax errors (sql server)